# Double break java

Tags: java, loops

I am programming with Java, and I do not understand how to use the break; command to get out of more than one loop.

Here is some code that I tried:

```
    while (true){
        System.out.println("\n\nBank Menu: \nWhat action do you want to perform(Enter a number)?\n\n1. Create a bank account \n2. Log in to a preexisting account \n3. Exit bank system");
        String action1 = scanner.next();
        if (action1.equals("1")) {
            if(!(password==null)){
                if(createAccountTracker==1){
                    createAccountTracker=0;
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Are you sure? Creating a new account will remove your preexisting account\n1.Yes\n2.Cancel");
                createaccount = scanner.next();

                if(createaccount.equals(2)) {
                    createAccountTracker=1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("What will your account name be(One Word Only)?");
            accName = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter your account password: ");
            passwordCheck1 = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Please reenter your account password: ");
            passwordCheck2 = scanner.next();
            if(passwordCheck1.equals(passwordCheck2)){
                password= passwordCheck2;
                System.out.println("Your account has been made!\n\nThank you for creating an account!\nAccount name: " + accName + "\nPassword: " + password );
                accBalance=0;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Error: Two passwords entered do not match. Please try again.");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to make it so that if they enter 2(cancel), the code will break out of the two loops and go back to the bank menu. The question I saw on SO did not really help me understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is your nested loop?

Comment: @Lashane I have already seen this, but that is a different case(using for loops).

Comment: all loops are the same

Comment: all loops behave the same when it comes to `break`

Comment: You only have a single loop shown and you do not check for the input to equal 2 so you might start there.

Comment: The linked answer is correct and your question is a duplicate (and should be closed).  This will work for any kind of loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can break out of 2 loops this way:

```
outer: 
while(condition) { // while or for loops, same way
    while(condition2) {
        break outer; // break out of the 2 loops
    }
}

// Other code
```

The "**outer**" label marks the outsider loop.

Comment: Once I use break outer; , it will jump out of all the loops and go to the first one?

Comment: It shall break out of the two loops and execute whatever code that comes after.

Comment: can I do this with continue?

Comment: nope, `continue` takes you to the next iteration, that's all it does. **It does not break loops.**

Comment: what if there is a third loop that I want to run?

Comment: Is this third loop nested inside those 2 previous loops or is it outside ?

Comment: The third loop is outside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96603/discussion-between-jdev-and-babyguineapig11).

Comment: `continue outer` would skip to the next iteration of the outer loop though

Comment: @babyguineapig11 if the third loop is outside then it shall be executed after breaking out of those two.